# Solr to list partial matches at top-different scenario

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search, search-engine

I have performed search against the field **company**   **(**which is ngram-d as i need to fetch results against partial match**)** with the search text **"aetnahmo"** . I could bring exact matches and partial matches very top. 
I need to handle a scenario such as:
Example:  From the below results, I need to bring "**AETNA BETTER HLTH PAHMO**" and "**AETNA BETTER HEALTH MAHMO**" at the top of "**CIGNAHMO HEALTHPLAN - METH**".
Here,even these results do not have 'aetnahmo' it has 'aetna'. I need to display results starts with this, below the exact matches and similar matches.

```
  "docs": [
  {
    "company": "AETNAHMOGNPIPA",
    "score": 0.32741508
  },
  {
    "company": "AETNAHMOPOSOUT OF NETWORK",
    "score": 0.32741508
  },
  {
    "company": "CIGNAHMO HEALTHPLAN - METH",
    "score": 0.14788051
  },
  {
    "company": "CIGNAHMOPOSOZ08",
    "score": 0.14500062
  },
  {
    "company": "CIGNAHMOPOSGNPIPA",
    "score": 0.14500062
  },
  {
    "company": "HUMANAHMO MCD",
    "score": 0.14500062
  },
  {
    "company": "AETNA BETTER HLTH PAHMO",
    "score": 0.1069743
  },
  {
    "company": "AETNA BETTER HEALTH MAHMO",
    "score": 0.1069743
  },
  {
    "company": "MOLINA HLTHCARE IL PAHMO",
    "score": 0.067287326
  },
  {
    "company": "BCBSMAHMO OUTPT",
    "score": 0.065203
  }
  ]
```

Is there a way to achieve this. Please help

Comment: What is your mingram size? It would be helpful if you could post the field definition

Comment: <fieldType name="TypoSearch" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30" />     
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>   
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

Comment: <fieldType name="TypeString" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

Comment: <fields>
  <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="company" stored="true" type="TypoSearch" termVectors="true" termPositions="true"  termOffsets="true"/>
  <field name="companyOriginal" type="TypeString" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
  </fields>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

Comment: What query parser are you using?

Comment: Default query parser

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back. I've posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Phrase boosting will work here.

You'll need to use the `edismax` query parser along with the `pf` field.

The following params appended to your query should do the trick:
`&defType=edismax&pf=company`.

I've tested this out on Solr-5.4.1 with the dataset that you've posted above and the results are as follows:

Query: `http://localhost:8983/solr/Test/select?q=company%3Aaetnamho&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&pf=company&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true&omitHeader=true`

Response:

```
{
"response":{"numFound":9,"start":0,"docs":[
  {
    "company":"AETNAHMOPOSOUT OF NETWORK",
    "id":2,
    "_version_":1530885533005250560},
  {
    "company":"AETNA BETTER HEALTH MAHMO",
    "id":8,
    "_version_":1530885600368918528},
  {
    "company":"AETNA BETTER HLTH PAHMO",
    "id":7,
    "_version_":1530885592734236672},
  {
    "company":"AETNAHMOGNPIPA",
    "id":1,
    "_version_":1530885512290631680},
  {
    "company":"CIGNAHMO HEALTHPLAN - METH",
    "id":3,
    "_version_":1530885543046414336},
  {
    "company":"MOLINA HLTHCARE IL PAHMO",
    "id":9,
    "_version_":1530885608894889984},
  {
    "company":"CIGNAHMOPOSGNPIPA",
    "id":5,
    "_version_":1530885565434560512},
  {
    "company":"CIGNAHMOPOSOZ08",
    "id":4,
    "_version_":1530885555631423488},
  {
    "company":"HUMANAHMO MCD",
    "id":6,
    "_version_":1530885585061806080}]
}}
```

Comment: : Thank you. But this is not worked for me. Can you please post the schema as well for the fields and fieldtype. I am using the fields and filedtypes that I posted Initially.

Comment: I've used the same. What results are you seeing?

Comment: Additionally, I just tried with this one field company. If you're also searching and/or scoring based on other fields, then the results you see will differ. In that case you'll have to play around with the pf boosting to come to the correct value that works for you.

Comment: Apart from company, I have fetched score as well.. Also I am searching against around 60000 docs. These are the only difference that I can see now.. I will check more and let you know the update soon

Comment: Sorry,this phrase query didnt work for me and I have just queried as you said. I have tried with newly created core as well for same set of data. But still I couldnt achieve the requirement. I couldnt find any difference and i am listing data in same order that I have posted initially.  I couldnt get where i am wrong

Comment: I tried this out on Solr 5.4.1 I think. What version of solr are you using?

Comment: I am using   Solr 5.5.0 version